# I want to change the mutipart parser in Struts 2.1 project to- pell multipart

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, multipartform-data, multipart

I have tried adding the required jar plugin for `pell` multipart in the lib directory. Also I have made the following entry to my struts.xml

```xml
<constant name="struts.multipart.parser" value="pell" />
```

But it does not seem to work. From the logs it is clear that the default `jakarta` parser is being referenced every time for file uploads.

Comment: I think some content didn't make it into your post.

Answer (score 0):

The pell parser is a plugin, that you need to download and include in the package. [From the docs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-AlternateLibraries):

> The pell parser uses Jason Pell's multipart parser instead of the `Commons-FileUpload` library. The pell parser is a Struts 2 plugin, for more details see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/S2PLUGINS/Pell+Multipart+Plugin.

And

> #### Installation
>
> This plugin can be installed by copying the plugin jar into your application's `/WEB-INF/lib` directory. The Pell Multipart library will need to be downloaded and included in your application as well. Due to its LGPL license, the library cannot be included in the Struts distribution.

---

Note: from 2.3.18+ [you can also use `jakarta-stream`](https://struts.apache.org/docs/file-upload.html) instead of `jakarta` or `pell`, to handle huge files and [reporting *FileTooBig* errors correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092457/1654265).

Comment: Can I instead use the JakartaSteamMultiPartRequest.java specified here: [WW-3025](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3025). This may serve as a workaround  for my current struts version 2.1.8.Will this be supported for my version of struts?

Comment: 2.3.18, not 2.1.8, sorry