# "Prefix too short" error when using JakartaStreamMultiPartRequest with empty file upload field

Tags: file-upload, struts2

I am using Struts 2.3.24.1 and after switching to the `jakarta-stream` implementation because of the bug mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085359/struts2-file-upload-loosing-parameters), I discovered a new error when the file upload field in my form is empty.
My form looks like this (abridged):

```jsp
<s:form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="persistAddNote" id="noteForm">
    <s:token/>
    <s:file name="fileUpload" size="79"/>
    <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
        <s:property value="%{#request.uploadError}" escape="false"/>
    </s:if>
    <s:submit cssClass="buttonFormat" value="Save"
              onclick="javascript: disableButtons(); document.noteForm.submit();"/>
</s:form>
```

The `persistAddNote` action is configured as follows:

```xml
<action name="persistAddNote" class="my.example.action.PersistNoteAction">
    <param name="parameter">my.example.encoder.Latin1ToLatin9Encoder</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref> 
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <exception-mapping name="notes.error.filesize"
                       exception="my.example.exception.UploadFileSizeException"
                       result="/notes/error.jsp"/>
    <result name="input">/notes/addnote.jsp</result>
    <result name="added">/notes/newnoteok.jsp</result>
    <result name="novalidaction">/notes/noValidActionError.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The error occurs in the `JakartaStreamMultiPartRequest.createTemporaryFile(String, String)` method because no filename is set. This is to be expected since the file upload field is not required. I tried debugging the Struts code but it looks as if the `multipart/form-data` enctype always triggers the creation of a temporary file. The error is gone when I switch back to the standard `jakarta` implementation in the `struts.properties` but that brings back the issue I mentioned above.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like a bug. You can report it [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW).

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks. At least my configuration is correct then which is kind of a relief ;-)

Comment: [WW-4583](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4583).

Comment: Thank you, Aleksandr. I am going to write an answer to my question in order to properly close it.

Comment: @AleksandrM One last question: Will there be a new snapshots deployment containing your fix? I just looked through the repository and the latest snapshot for version 2.3.25 dates back to october. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Not sure for the 2.3.25 snapshots. :( You can get a jar from Jenkins build. See my answer for simple workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aleksandr mentioned, it was a bug in the `JakartaStreamMultiPartRequest` (see [WW-4583](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4583)). The bug has been fixed in version 2.3.28 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Until the new version is released you can apply simple JavaScript workaround to *fix* this issue. Just disable file input field if it is empty prior to submitting.

```js
function checkFileInput() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInputId");
    if (fileInput.value.length < 1) {
        fileInput.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ignore downvote here, it is just a retaliation for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34672502/1700321) ;)

Comment: I wondered for a second but I had the power to equalize it ;) Thank you again. You have been a big help in this.

Comment: @Sebastian: Thanks. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @Abdelhak: It would be good of you to remove downvotes on my posts also.

Comment: God, not dv-ers again -.-