# node.js - streaming upload to cloud storage (busboy, request)

Tags: node.js, upload, request, streaming, busboy

I'm new to node.js.  What I'm trying to do is to stream the upload of a file from web browser to a cloud storage through my node.js server.

I'm using 'express', 'request' and 'busboy' modules.

```js
var express = require("express");
var request = require("request");
var BusBoy = require("busboy");
var router = express.Router();

router.post("/upload", function(req, res, next) {
    var busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });
    var json = {};

    busboy.on("file", function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        file.on("data", function(data) {
            console.log(`streamed ${data.length}`);
        });

        file.on("end", function() {
            console.log(`finished streaming ${filename}`);
        });
        
        var r = request({
            url: "http://<my_cloud_storage_api_url>",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "CUSTOM-HEADER": "Hello",
            },
            formData: {
                "upload": file
            }
        }, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
            console.log("uploaded");
            json.response = body;
        });
    });

    busboy.on("field", function(name, val) {
        console.log(`name: ${name}, value: ${value}`);
    });
    
    busboy.on("finish", function() {
        res.send(json);
    });

    req.pipe(busboy);
});

module.exports = router;
```

But I keep getting the following error on the server.  What am I doing wrong here?  Any help is appreciated.

```
Error: Part terminated early due to unexpected end of multipart data
at node_modules\busboy\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:65:36
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is some 7 months old, but I shall answer it here in an attempt help anyone else currently banging their head against this.

You have two options, really: Add the file size, or use something other than Request.

Note: I edited this shortly after first posting it to hopefully provide a bit more context.

#### Using Something Else

There are some alternatives you can use instead of Request if you don't need all the baked in features it has.

- [`form-data`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) can be used by itself in simple cases, or it can be used with, say, `got`.  `request` uses this internally.
- [`bhttp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bhttp) advertises Streams2+ support, although in my experience Streams2+ support has not been an issue for me.  No built in `https` support, you have to specify a [custom agent](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_agent)
- [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) another slimmed down one.  Doesn't have any special handling of form data like `request` does, but is trivially used with `form-data` or `form-data2`.  I had trouble getting it working over a corporate proxy, though, but that's likely because I'm a networking newb.
- [`needle`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle) seems pretty light weight, but I haven't actually tried it.

#### Using Request: Add the File Size

[Request](https://github.com/request/request) does not (as of writing) have any support for using `transfer-encoding: chunked` so to upload files with it, you need to add the file's size along with the file, which if you're uploading from a web client means that client needs to send that file size to your server in addition to the file itself.

The way I came up with to do this is to send the file metadata in its own field before the file field.

I modified your example with comments describing what I did.  Note that I did not include any validation of the data received, but I recommend you do add that.

```js
var express = require("express");
var request = require("request");
var BusBoy = require("busboy");
var router = express.Router();

router.post("/upload", function(req, res, next) {
    var busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });
    var json = {};

    // Use this to cache any fields which are file metadata.
    var fileMetas = {};

    busboy.on("file", function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        // Be sure to match this prop name here with the pattern you use to detect meta fields.
        var meta = fileMetas[fieldname + '.meta'];

        if (!meta) {
            // Make sure to dump the file.
            file.resume();
            // Then, do some sort of error handling here, because you cannot upload a file
            // without knowing it's length.
            return;
        }

        file.on("data", function(data) {
            console.log(`streamed ${data.length}`);
        });

        file.on("end", function() {
            console.log(`finished streaming ${filename}`);
        });

        var r = request({
            url: "http://<my_cloud_storage_api_url>",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "CUSTOM-HEADER": "Hello",
            },
            formData: {
                // value + options form of a formData field.
                "upload": {
                    value: file,
                    options: {
                        filename: meta.name,
                        knownLength: meta.size
                    }
                }
            }
        }, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
            console.log("uploaded");
            json.response = body;
        });
    });

    busboy.on("field", function(name, val) {
        // Use whatever pattern you want.  I used (fileFieldName + ".meta").
        // Another good one might be ("meta:" + fileFieldName).
        if (/\.meta$/.test(name)) {
            // I send an object with { name, size, type, lastModified },
            // which are just the public props pulled off a File object.
            // Note: Should probably add error handling if val is somehow not parsable.
            fileMetas[name] = JSON.parse(val);
            console.log(`file metadata: name: ${name}, value: ${value}`);
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise, process field as normal.
        console.log(`name: ${name}, value: ${value}`);
    });

    busboy.on("finish", function() {
        res.send(json);
    });

    req.pipe(busboy);
});

module.exports = router;
```

On the client, you need to then send the metadata on the so-named field *before* the file itself.  This can be done by ordering an `<input type="hidden">` control before the file and updating its value `onchange`.  [The order of values sent is guaranteed to follow the order of inputs in appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449861/multipart-upload-form-is-order-guaranteed).  If you're building the request body yourself using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), you can do this by appending the appropriate metadata before appending the `File`.

Example with `<form>`

```html
<script>
    function extractFileMeta(file) {
        return JSON.stringify({
            size: file.size,
            name: file.name,
            type: file.type,
            lastUpdated: file.lastUpdated
        });
    }

    function onFileUploadChange(event) {
        // change this to use arrays if using the multiple attribute on the file input.
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        var fileMetaInput = document.querySelector('input[name=fileUpload.meta]');

        if (fileMetaInput) {
            fileMetaInput.value = extractFileMeta(file);
        }
    }
</script>
<form action="/upload-to-cloud">
    <input type="hidden" name="fileUpload.meta">
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" onchange="onFileUploadChange(event)">
</form>
```

Example with `FormData`:

```js
function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = document.getElementById('my-upload-form');
    var formData = new FormData();

    var fileUpload = form.elements['fileUpload'];
    var fileUploadMeta = JSON.stringify({
        size: fileUpload.size,
        name: fileUpload.name,
        type: fileUpload.type,
        lastUpdated: fileUpload.lastUpdated
    });

    // Append fileUploadMeta BEFORE fileUpload.
    formData.append('fileUpload.meta', fileUploadMeta);
    formData.append('fileUpload', fileUpload);

    // Do whatever you do to POST here.
}
```