# Safari 11.1: ajax/XHR form submission fails when input[type=file] is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, safari

**UPDATE**: As of [Webkit build r230963](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/230963/webkit), this issue has been resolved in Webkit.

===========

Since the recent Safari 11.1 update on macOS and iOS, as well as in Safari Technology Preview 11.2, the `$.ajax` calls in my web application are failing when a `input[type=file]` field has no file chosen (it isn't required in my form). No failure when the field *does* have a file chosen.

The `error` callback of `ajax` runs and the Safari console contains the following message: `Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Protocol error`. I am HTTPS and submitting to a location on the same domain (and server) also over HTTPS.

Before the 11.1 update, the `$.ajax` call submitted just fine when no file was chosen. The latest versions of Chrome and Firefox have no issues.

Relevant parts of my code:

The input:

```
Browse... <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="image" accept=".jpg,.jpeg">
```

The JS:

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    url: '../process.php',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) { ... },
    error: function() { //my code reaches here }
});
```

As a temporary (hopefully) solution, I'm detecting an empty file field and removing it from `formData` before the `ajax` call and everything works as expected/before:

```
$("input[type=file]").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "") {
        formData.delete($(this).attr("name"));
    }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong, is there an issue with Safari, or is there a change in Safari that needs to be accounted for now in ajax calls?

Comment: Great temporary solution, but doens't work below safari 11 if applied to all Safari browsers. Did you find any "real" solution yet?

Comment: @Karem - Thanks for that heads up! Fortunately, the users of my application won't be below Safari 11 but that's good to know. And no, no solution yet. I filed a radar/bug report with Apple and they just today asked for sys diagnostics which I will be sending.

Comment: Had the same issue and this post helped me so much.  Thank you.  FWIW I believe FormDeta#delete() is only supported in Safari 11 or later.  So you might have to add a version check.   https://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2  Anyway, thank you for your info.

Comment: Yeah delete() may be it. Any suggestions on how to add a version check with javascript?

Comment: @Matt. thank you. Do you have a link towards the Apple report you filed ?

Comment: @Laurent.B I don't since it was filed via Bug Reporter on Apple's Developer website. (Unless there's a way to share those)

Comment: @Matt I don't know, I'm not an Apple user. I suggest (if not already done) that you send them the link to this Q/A. There are few others concerning the same problem with Safari (it's not so new as I thought it at first)... They may not be aware :/

Comment: @Laurent.B In my bug report, I did originally provide a link to this StackOverflow page. So hopefully that helps them.

Comment: @Matt perfect. Thx

Comment: There is bugzilla item open for WebKit, and also a rdar it seems.
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184490

Comment: A fix has been committed to Webkit https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/230963/webkit. Will wait for next build with this in it to test.

Comment: Yes, the issue has been resolved, I can confirm. No idea when it will be in the public release.

Comment: This still is an issue for me in iOS 11.4. And the provided solution does not work

Comment: @ErickMaynard The fix has not made it into the version of Safari in iOS 11.4. I also doubt it'll make it in the public release of macOS 10.13.5. The provided solution does work. People can help you if you share what you've tried and/or what you have :)

Comment: In Safari that's included in iOS 12 beta 1 has the bug fix included. I assume the same is true for macOS Mojave beta 1.

Comment: Any idea when this will make it's way to Safari for everyday users?

Comment: @drooh Not until Safari 12, which will release when iOS 12 and macOS Mojave release, likely mid-September.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of [Webkit build r230963](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/230963/webkit), this issue has been resolved in Webkit. I downloaded and ran that build and confirmed the issue is resolved. Not idea when a public release will be available for Safari that contains this fix.

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATE: Old answer does NOT work in Firefox.**

Firefox returns **just empty string** for `FormData.get()` on empty file field (instead of File object in other browsers). So when using old workaround, empty `<input type="file">` will be sent like as empty `<input type="text">`. Unfortunately, there is no way to distinguish an empty file from an empty text after creating FormData object.

Use this solution instead:

```
var $form = $('form')
var $inputs = $('input[type="file"]:not([disabled])', $form)
$inputs.each(function(_, input) {
  if (input.files.length > 0) return
  $(input).prop('disabled', true)
})
var formData = new FormData($form[0])
$inputs.prop('disabled', false)
```

Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ypresto/05Lc45eL/

For non-jQuery environment:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form')
var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]:not([disabled])')
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  if (input.files.length > 0) return
  input.setAttribute('disabled', '')
})
var formData = new FormData(form)
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.removeAttribute('disabled')
})
```

For Rails (rails-ujs/jQuery-ujs): https://gist.github.com/ypresto/cabce63b1f4ab57247e1f836668a00a5

---

Old Answer:

Filtering FormData (in Ravichandra Adiga's answer) is better because it does not manipulate any DOM.

But [the order of parts in FormData is guaranteed to be the same order to input elements in form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7450170/1474113), according to `<form>` specification. It could cause another bug if someone relies on this spec.

Below snippet will keep FormData order and empty part.

```
var formDataFilter = function(formData) {
    // Replace empty File with empty Blob.
  if (!(formData instanceof window.FormData)) return
  if (!formData.keys) return // unsupported browser
  var newFormData = new window.FormData()
  Array.from(formData.entries()).forEach(function(entry) {
    var value = entry[1]
    if (value instanceof window.File && value.name === '' && value.size === 0) {
      newFormData.append(entry[0], new window.Blob(), '')
    } else {
      newFormData.append(entry[0], value)
    }
  })
  return newFormData
}
```

Live example is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ypresto/y6v333bq/

For Rails, see here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32440#issuecomment-381185380

(NOTE: iOS 11.3's Safari has this issue but 11.2 is not.)

Comment: Thanks @ypresto. I’ll be investigating this! Btw, iOS 11.2 uses Safari 11.0.3, which is why the issue is not present there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We have nginx error 400 on iphone browsers and this trick saved us!

Answer (score 6):

For workaround I delete the input type file completely from DOM using jQuery remove() method.

```js
$("input[type=file]").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "") {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I’d have to restore the field within the always() method. Once the AJAX call is done, the user needs to interact with the form again, including the file inputs.

Comment: I understand perhaps you should add them back in callback of Ajax method, this workaround worked for me.

Comment: You could just add a "disabled" attribute on the input, so it wouldn't be collected in the form data; you can then remove the attribute when you have files to upload.

Comment: @MatteoSteccolini solution works, I used this instead of remove. $(this).prop("disabled", true);  and if you need it back just do the same with $(this).prop("disabled", false);

Answer (score 2):

I worked on what appears to be the same issue in a Perl-program

[Processing multipart/form-data in Perl invokes Apache-error with Apple-devices, when a form-file-element is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040739/processing-multipart-form-data-in-perl-invokes-apache-error-with-apple-devices)

Workaround is removing the form-elements before the formdata is assigned:

```
$('#myForm').find("input[type='file']").each(function(){
    if ($(this).get(0).files.length === 0) {$(this).remove();}
});
var fData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
...
```

Comment: This is totally true, you saved my life! This is a must do for safari if you're uploading files with ajax

Answer (score 1):

```
    var fileNames = formData.getAll("filename[]");
    formData.delete("filename[]");
    jQuery.each(fileNames, function (key, fileNameObject) {
        if (fileNameObject.name) {
            formData.append("filename[]", fileNameObject);
        }
    });
```

Try this !!

Comment: My temporary solution works for the time being until this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to check if the input field is empty. If empty, disable the input field before created the FormData. After created the FormData, remove the "disabled" attribute. The difference to other answers is, that I search for "input[0].files.length == 0".

```
// get the input field with type="file"
var input = $('#myForm').find("input[type='file']")

// add the "disabled" attribute to the input
if (input[0].files.length == 0) {
  input.prop('disabled', true);
}

// create the formdata  
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

// remove the "disabled" attribute
input.prop('disabled', false);
```